# Is it possible to replace Rope for refactoring of python code in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, refactoring, rope

As far as I understand - Rope is not supported now: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/10440.

How can I replace it by something else ?

I don't see refactor extensions available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pylsp-rope](https://github.com/python-rope/pylsp-rope) to use Rope from any editors that supports LSP.

Disclosure: I am the author of pylsp-rope and maintainer of rope.